# Failed to minify the code from this file

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify, uglifyjs2

I am authoring a JavaScript library that I want to put on `npm`. I am currently using that library in another project and I have added it as a dependency using its GitHub repository:

```
"dependencies": {
  // ... others
  "react-web-component": "LukasBombach/react-web-component",
}
```

I am also using Webpack with the `UglifyJsPlugin`. Now when I want to build my project I get an error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> Failed to minify the code from this file:
>
> ./packages/react-scripts/node_modules/react-web-component/src/index.js line 18:0
>
> Read more here: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify
>
> error Command failed with exit code 1.

This is a problem of my library. When I remove it from my deps (and from my code) compiling works.

I cannot figure out what the problem is, my code seems pretty straight forward:

```
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const retargetEvents = require('./retargetEvents');
const getStyleElementsFromReactWebComponentStyleLoader = require('./getStyleElementsFromReactWebComponentStyleLoader');

module.exports = {
  create: function(app, tagName, options) {
    const proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
      attachedCallback: {
        value: function() {
          const shadowRoot = this.createShadowRoot();
          const mountPoint = document.createElement('div');
          getStyleElementsFromReactWebComponentStyleLoader().forEach(style =>
            shadowRoot.appendChild(style)
          );
          shadowRoot.appendChild(mountPoint);
          ReactDOM.render(app, mountPoint);
          retargetEvents(shadowRoot);
        },
      },
    });
    document.registerElement(tagName, { prototype: proto });
  },
};
```

Inside the `retargetEvents` and `getStyleElementsFromReactWebComponentStyleLoader` requires there are simple `module.export` commands. You can see their source code [here](https://github.com/LukasBombach/react-web-component/blob/master/src/retargetEvents.js) and [here](https://github.com/LukasBombach/react-web-component/blob/master/src/getStyleElementsFromReactWebComponentStyleLoader.js).

I have already tried publishing my library using ES6 export / import commands.

The full source code of my library (it's just these 3 files) can be found at https://github.com/LukasBombach/react-web-component

Comment: you forgot to add react tag.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you mean that I have not required the React library. That is not the problem, I don't need it here.

Comment: no. Since there is react codes, I think react have to do something which I am unsure. If yes, adding the tag react will help you to bring this question to react devs

Comment: It really is not the problem, since I am not using React here. I am using a compiled react class that for me functions is just an arbitrary object

Comment: I found the solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution!

I had some ES6 features in my code, namely `foreach` the `~` operator and shorthand function syntax. The uglyfier did not accept that. I needed to replace that with ES5 code and it works well now.

Comment: What do you do if the code is in one or more of your `node_modules` packages?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter were you able to find a solution for node packages?

Comment: @shivavelingker I believe I ended up using a different node package that was already precompiled to ES5 and worked with Electron. If you find a better solution, please it here.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter It worked with updating the react script, as it was resolving .mjs before .js .  ```npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@1.1.2```

Comment: As @HarishRana suggested, it worked for me: same error (trying to minify PNotify 4.0-alpha.4) was fixed updating 'react-scripts=1.1.5' to '2.05' (latest) at the package.json. The option of JoshuaPinter is another good workaround.

Comment: I wouldn't call downgrading a solution.  You're going have to eventually figure out a better solution.

Comment: While changing the source itself makes sense in this case (after all it's your own library that you're importing in your project), in general you can try adding/modifying *a transpilation step* before minification (e.g. add the library dir to `include` list of your `babel-loader` config, if using webpack + babel) - esp. for third-party libraries outside of your control.

Answer (score 18):

For those you are facing the problem. First check your package.json whether you are using React-script 1.x. If so try upgrade to 2.x.x.

From the official Troubleshooting docs [npm run build fails to minify](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/troubleshooting#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify)

> npm run build fails to minify Before `react-scripts@2.0.0`, this problem
>   was caused by third party `node_modules` using modern JavaScript
>   features because the minifier couldn't handle them during the build.
>   This has been solved by compiling standard modern JavaScript features
>   inside `node_modules` in `react-scripts@2.0.0` and higher.
>
> If you're seeing this error, you're likely using an old version of
>   `react-scripts`. You can either fix it by avoiding a dependency that
>   uses modern syntax, or by upgrading to `react-scripts@>=2.0.0` and
>   following the migration instructions in the changelog.

Upgrade by.

```
npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@2.x.x
```

or

```
yarn add --exact react-scripts@2.x.x
```

Answer (score 12):

For people that still face this issue, here I found a solution that worked for me; I will explain it step by step here:

Recently I involved in a project that uses an older version of `create-react-app` with `webpack@3` and `uglifyJsPlugin` in it's webpack configuration. While I worked with the project the main issue and problem raised when I installed other npm packages and I worked with them for a while in dev mode. After I've done my tasks on them, when I wanted to build the project, I faced with the headache of:

```
cannot minify code from this file blah blah blah...
```

The problem raised from minifying the js files so t thought that if I change the configuration of `webpack.config.prod` to change the minification process of it, then I would be able to solve the problem. So I checked the `webpack.config.prod` file and I saw that it uses the `uglifyJsPlugin` for minification. I changed the configuration to use `terser-webpack-plugin` and I got another error that would state that this pkg is for `webpack@4`. Finally I ended up using `terser-webpack-plugin-legacy` for my `webpack@3` configuration and it worked perfectly. Please note that my `create-react-app` was ejected.

Comment: This was the only realistic solution for me. I just added the Terser Plugin where the old UglifyJsPlugin (despite the official docs). I'm curious what is your actual setup

Comment: Saved my day, thank you! I had the same issue and webpack/react setup, with react-app being rejected. Simply removing `uglifyJsPlugin` and replacing with `terser-webpack-plugin-legacy` fixed the webpack minification issue. Just by using `new TerserPlugin(),`in webpack config. Legacy documentation was a bit confusing for webpack 3.x.x config. The build size has actually improved as well now \o/

Comment: It also worked for me, I lost my entire day trying to figure out what was going on. But finally it worked

Comment: You can also try adding/modifying *a transpilation step* before minification (e.g. add the library dir to `include` list of your `babel-loader` config, if using webpack + babel).

Comment: I don't understand how I change these settings? Who can help me please?

Comment: This is what is written in my file
 `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({`

Answer (score 3):

For anyone having this issue where upgrading `react-scripts` isn't the solution, this my story:

First, I use `vscode` with some auto import plugin that automatically adds the import at the top. It was working ok... until yesterday.

Today I ran the deploy script on my local branch (last time I ran it was last week) and I got this horrible error message, particularly:

```
Failed to minify the code from this file:

    ./node_modules/re-reselect/src/cache/FifoObjectCache.js:4
```

It didn't make sense because `master` build was working fine and I hadn't updated my packages since then.

Hopeless, I started to build commit by commit (actually I started with some of the first ones, then when it worked tried with some other in the middle, and so on) looking for the culprit.

And then I found it!

The auto import plugin added the following import to my code:

```
import createCachedSelector from 're-reselect/src/index';
```

when it should be:

```
import createCachedSelector from 're-reselect';
```

Causing some `reselect` source files to be compiled instead of using the already compiled ones by the library.

TL;DR;
Do not trust your auto import plugin. Never. Ever. :facepalm:

Comment: That thing is notorious

Comment: Took me three days but I finally found it --> 
import { cloneDeep } from '@babel/types'; 
instead of --> 
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep';

Comment: Turning them off now in settings --> 
"typescript.suggest.autoImports": false 
"javascript.suggest.autoImports": false

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this by importing minified version of external library.
F.E. for socket.io-client change

`import io from 'socket.io-client';`

to

`import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js';`

Answer (score 0):

First change from package.json. "react-scripts": "2.0.3",

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

Answer (score 0):

1. I recommend deleteing the any build file and node module file.
2. Delete package-lock.json file
3. In package.json replace `"react-scripts"` with `"react-scripts": "^5.0.1"`
4. run `npm install` and then`npm audit fix --force` to fix issues

These things worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
*delete node_modules, and only revert/downgrade version of the problem making dependency to a previously working ES5 supported version in both package-lock.json and package.json. No need to delete the entire package-lock.json file.*

This **error** will mostly **occur** for many, suddenly when everything was working fine. This is because any of your **dependency** has been **updated** to a recent **version**. Recently most scripting is done **with ES6** standards and your `uglify-js` code which may be of an older version will **fail to minify** this code.

Now as mentioned in previous answers only **deleting** the **package-lock.json** and **node_modules** will **not work**. You **must also reset** the version of the updated dependency in **package.json** file. But this will have 2 challenges:-

1. This will **update** some of your **other dependencies** to a recent version. Which may also **lead** to **syntax** error or any other **compatibility** related **issues**.
2. This will **create** a **new package-lock.json** file, which will have an updated dependency tree. **Doing this** for any one issue with any one dependency is **not** a **decent** way to solve this. The **reason** **being** if your **code** is **part** **of** any **version control** system, then this **change** will get **reflected** there as well. And **ideally**, such **changes** to **dependency tree** must be a **planned activity** among team members with **thorough testing** of your code.

So **to solve** this, just **revert/downgrade** the **version** in package.json file, and change the version and npmjs package download url in ***resolved*** field for that singular dependency in **package-lock.json** file. For me this issue was happening because of `react-lazy-load-image-component` dependency. So **instead** of **deleting** the entire **dependency tree**, I just **deleted node_modules**, **and reverted** **to** an **older ES5 version** in package.json and package-lock.json file.

In package-lock.json I changed this:

```
"react-lazy-load-image-component": {
            "version": "1.5.6",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-lazy-load-image-component/-/react-lazy-load-image-component-1.5.6.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-M0jeJtOlTHgThOfgYM9krSqYbR6ShxROy/KVankwbw9/amPKG1t5GSGN1sei6Cyu8+QJVuyAUvQ+LFtCVTTlKw==",
            "requires": {
                "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
                "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1"
            }
        },
```

To this:

```
"react-lazy-load-image-component": {
            "version": "1.3.2",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-lazy-load-image-component/-/react-lazy-load-image-component-1.3.2.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-LLbsFQwIV4TdlObBYjlJyRSmYMadd8pMOsYmihFAI6nXBgOEYVuRJlq7T0PjT5OWzntV38VvSw+P+NJU7etH3Q==",
            "requires": {
                "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
                "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1"
            }
        },
```