# React build failed to minify the bundle error from UglifyJs (build failed while minifying the pdfjs-dist library)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, pdfjs-dist

Here is an error (my project works correctly on dev, but when I try to build it, it throws me this error)

```
> node-react-sample@0.1.0 build /home/acquaint/WORK_DIRECTORY/altr
> node scripts/build.js

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file: 

        ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:341 

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-react-sample@0.1.0 build: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-react-sample@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

[Build Failed with this error (check screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGXL.png)

Comment: any solutions for this?

Comment: @Vaulstein The solution is you need to degrade your pdfjs-dist version. Try this one (2.0.943 is the stable version).

Comment: Have you checked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671597/failed-to-minify-the-code-from-this-file ?