# How to know if minification process is successful after deployment?

Tags: webpack, bundling-and-minification, uglifyjs, terser-webpack-plugin

I am facing issue running npm run build during the minification process as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671597/failed-to-minify-the-code-from-this-file). Most of the solutions given is to upgrade to react-scripts v2.x.x is not a viable option for me. So I am currently implementing [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671597/failed-to-minify-the-code-from-this-file/56472018#56472018) which suggests to use terser-webpack-plugin-legacy instead of UglifyJS for the minification process.

I was able to build successfully. But I'm not sure if what I did is correct and I have no idea how to ensure that the minification process was successful.

I compared between the Sources tab under chrome dev tools and see that using UglifyJS there is static/js folder while when using Terser, there isn't a static/js folder

[Dev Tools screenshot with UglifyJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLzXJ.png)

[Dev tools screenshot using terser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drf9e.png)

This is a snippet of my old webpack.config.prod.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // Minify the code.
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        // Disabled because of an issue with Uglify breaking seemingly valid code:
        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2376
        // Pending further investigation:
        // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2011
        comparisons: false,
      },
      mangle: {
        safari10: true,
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
        // Turned on because emoji and regex is not minified properly using default
        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2488
        ascii_only: true,
      },
      sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
    }),
```

And this is the new config

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // Minify the code.
    new TerserPlugin({
      terserOptions:{
        compress: {
          warnings: false,
          // Disabled because of an issue with Uglify breaking seemingly valid code:
          // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2376
          // Pending further investigation:
          // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2011
          comparisons: false,
        },
        mangle: {
          safari10: true,
        },
        output: {
          comments: false,
          // Turned on because emoji and regex is not minified properly using default
          // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2488
          ascii_only: true,
        },
      },
      sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
    }),
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-web-project",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "./",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.2.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.2",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "material-ui-chip-input": "^1.1.0",
    "material-ui-flat-pagination": "^2.1.4",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.36",
    "mdi-material-ui": "^5.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "patch-package": "^6.0.5",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "print-js": "^1.0.54",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-bootstrap-modal": "^4.2.0",
    "react-calendar": "^2.17.5",
    "react-content-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "react-csv": "^1.0.16",
    "react-day-picker": "^7.2.4",
    "react-dev-utils": "^4.2.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^7.0.1",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-number-format": "^4.0.5",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "react-slidedown": "^2.0.7",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.12.18",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "react-validation": "^3.0.7",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
    "recharts": "^1.5.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-saga": "^0.15.6",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "suneditor": "^2.41.3",
    "suneditor-react": "^2.16.5",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.7.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.2.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "terser": {
      "terserOptions": {
        "exclude": "node_modules/suneditor-react/dist/main.js"
      }
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 start",
    "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build",
    "build:ci": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=12288 build",
    "postinstall": "npx patch-package",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          "cwd": "babelrc",
          "root": "./src",
          "alias": {
            "ambank-language": "./src/_asset/language"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "error"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "terser-webpack-plugin-legacy": "^1.2.5"
  }
}
```